# Prediction interval in auto arima python

Tags: python, intervals, prediction, arima

I want to calculate .95 prediction interval using auto arima in python .I want to get the standard error of forecast like we can get in stats predict in R.

Then I will use the formula - point forecast ± 1.96 * Standard error of forecast at that time t to get upper and lower bounds.

How can I get the standard error of forecast for this in python. I am using auto arima predict for this. I know that statsmodel forecast has std error parameter to get these but I am using Auto arima predict.  Please tell me how can I get the prediction interval for 10 time steps in auto arima? The return Conf interval parameter returns very wide upper and lower range interval.  How can I get the standard error of forecasting for arima (1 0 2) order.

Comment: Are you using: https://www.alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/index.html ?

Comment: Using pmdarima. The built in return confidence interval forecasts .05 alpha are very wide to make sense.

Comment: Anyone can show the manual calculation process for order 1,0,2 arima

Comment: Can anyone help reply please. Need to predict multi step prediction interval for 20 step time period .Using Sarimax model of order 1 0 2

Answer (score 7):

Auto arima works by wrapping `statsmodels.tsa.ARIMA` and `statsmodels.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX` together as an estimator. You may extract the results the same way you do it with statsmodels. Here is a sample model:

```
 model = auto_arima(y_train, start_p=0, start_q=0,
            test='adf',       
            max_p=7, max_q=7, 
            m=np.int(season),             
            d=n_diffs,           
            seasonal=True,  
            start_P=0, 
            D=1, 
            trace=True,
            error_action='ignore',  
            suppress_warnings=True, 
            stepwise=True)
```

and

```
print(model.conf_int())
```

would return you an array with 95 % confidence interval of fitted parameters. Please feel free to go through this documentation [SARIMAX results](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAXResults.html) to know more about results of the model.

For 10 step prediction, you may do the following to get the confidence interval:

```
y_forec, conf_int  = model.predict(10,return_conf_int=True,alpha=0.05)
print(conf_int)
```

To get model standard error, you may extract the standard error with:

```
std_error = model.bse()
```

To get prediction standard error, the confidence intervals shall be used to obtain the standard error. Here is an answer explaining the same: [std_err for forecast](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/359116/obtaining-standard-errors-from-forecast-object-in-r)
[wiki for standard error and pred interval relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error)

Comment: Looks correct, the underlying API docs can be found here https://www.alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/auto_examples/arima/example_auto_arima.html?highlight=conf_int