# Statsmodels ARIMA: how to get confidence/prediction interval?

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima

How to generate "lower" and "upper" predictions, not just "yhat"?

```py
import statsmodels
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA

assert statsmodels.__version__ == '0.12.0'

arima = ARIMA(df['value'], order=order)
model = arima.fit()
```

Now I can generate "yhat" predictions

```py
yhat = model.forecast(123)
```

and get confidence intervals for model parameters (but not for predictions):

```py
model.conf_int()
```

but how to generate `yhat_lower` and `yhat_upper` predictions?

Answer (score 16):

In general, the `forecast` and `predict` methods only produce point predictions, while the `get_forecast` and `get_prediction` methods produce full results including prediction intervals.

In your example, you can do:

```
forecast = model.get_forecast(123)
yhat = forecast.predicted_mean
yhat_conf_int = forecast.conf_int(alpha=0.05)
```

If your data is a Pandas Series, then `yhat_conf_int` will be a DataFrame with two columns, `lower <name>` and `upper <name>`, where `<name>` is the name of the Pandas Series.

If your data is a numpy array (or Python list), then `yhat_conf_int` will be an `(n_forecasts, 2)` array, where the first column is the lower part of the interval and the second column is the upper part.

Comment: One should differ confidence intervals from prediction intervals, also a mean estimation and point prediction. These are different terms, concepts, and go under different calculations.

Answer (score 2):

using ARIMA you need to include seasonality and exogenous variables in the model yourself. While using SARIMA (Seasonal ARIMA) or SARIMAX (also for exogenous factors) implementation give C.I. to summary_frame:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dta = sm.datasets.sunspots.load_pandas().data[['SUNACTIVITY']]
dta.index = pd.Index(pd.date_range("1700", end="2009", freq="A"))
print(dta)
print("init data:\n")
dta.plot(figsize=(12,4));
plt.show()

##print("SARIMAX(dta, order=(2,0,0), trend='c'):\n")
result = sm.tsa.SARIMAX(dta, order=(2,0,0), trend='c').fit(disp=False)
print(">>> result.params:\n", result.params, "\n")

##print("SARIMA_model.plot_diagnostics:\n")
result.plot_diagnostics(figsize=(15,12))
plt.show()    
# summary stats of residuals
print(">>> residuals.describe:\n", result.resid.describe(), "\n")

# Out-of-sample forecasts are produced using the forecast or get_forecast methods from the results object
# The get_forecast method is more general, and also allows constructing confidence intervals.
fcast_res1 = result.get_forecast()
# specify that we want a confidence level of 90%
print(">>> forecast summary at alpha=0.01:\n", fcast_res1.summary_frame(alpha=0.10), "\n")

# plot forecast
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 5))    
# Construct the forecasts
fcast = result.get_forecast('2010Q4').summary_frame()
print(fcast)
fcast['mean'].plot(ax=ax, style='k--')
ax.fill_between(fcast.index, fcast['mean_ci_lower'], fcast['mean_ci_upper'], color='k', alpha=0.1);    
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_forecasting.html#Plotting-the-data,-forecasts,-and-confidence-intervals): "The forecast above may not look very impressive, as it is almost a straight line. This is because this is a very simple, univariate forecasting model. Nonetheless, keep in mind that these simple forecasting models can be extremely competitive"

p.s. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69529884/15893581) " you can use it in a non-seasonal way by setting the seasonal terms to zero."

Answer (score 0):

To generate prediction intervals as opposed to confidence intervals (which you have neatly made the distinction between, and is also presented in Hyndman's blog post on the [difference between prediction intervals and confidence intervals](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/intervals/)), then you can follow the guidance available in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57215346/13416265).

You could also try to compute bootstrapped prediction intervals, which is laid out in this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/254321).

Below, is my attempt at implementing this (I'll update it when I get the chance to check it in more detail):

```py
def bootstrap_prediction_interval(y_train: Union[list, pd.Series],
                                  y_fit: Union[list, pd.Series],
                                  y_pred_value: float,
                                  alpha: float = 0.05,
                                  nbootstrap: int = None,
                                  seed: int = None):
    """
    Bootstraps a prediction interval around an ARIMA model's predictions.
    Method presented clearly here:
        - https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/254321
    Also found through here, though less clearly:
        - https://otexts.com/fpp3/prediction-intervals.html
    Can consider this to be a time-series version of the following generalisation:
        - https://saattrupdan.github.io/2020-03-01-bootstrap-prediction/

    :param y_train: List or Series of training univariate time-series data.
    :param y_fit: List or Series of model fitted univariate time-series data.
    :param y_pred_value: Float of the model predicted univariate time-series you want to compute P.I. for.
    :param alpha: float = 0.05, the prediction uncertainty.
    :param nbootstrap: integer = 1000, the number of bootstrap sampling of the residual forecast error.
        Rules of thumb provided here:
            - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86040/rule-of-thumb-for-number-of-bootstrap-samples
    :param seed: Integer to specify if you want deterministic sampling.

    :return: A list [`lower`, `pred`, `upper`] with `pred` being the prediction
    of the model and `lower` and `upper` constituting the lower- and upper
    bounds for the prediction interval around `pred`, respectively.
    """

    # get number of samples
    n = len(y_train)

    # compute the forecast errors/resid
    fe = y_train - y_fit

    # get percentile bounds
    percentile_lower = (alpha * 100) / 2
    percentile_higher = 100 - percentile_lower

    if nbootstrap is None:
        nbootstrap = np.sqrt(n).astype(int)
    if seed is None:
        rng = np.random.default_rng()
    else:
        rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)

    # bootstrap sample from errors
    error_bootstrap = []
    for _ in range(nbootstrap):
        idx = rng.integers(low=n)
        error_bootstrap.append(fe[idx])

    # get lower and higher percentiles of sampled forecast errors
    fe_lower = np.percentile(a=error_bootstrap, q=percentile_lower)
    fe_higher = np.percentile(a=error_bootstrap, q=percentile_higher)

    # compute P.I.
    pi = [y_pred_value + fe_lower, y_pred_value, y_pred_value + fe_higher]

    return pi
```