# auto_arima(... , seasonal=False) but got SARIMAX 

Tags: python, pandas, arima, pmdarima

I want to know the orders (p,d,q) for ARIMA model, so I've got to use [`pmdarima`](https://pypi.org/project/pmdarima/) python package. but it recommends me **SARIMAX** model! keep reading for more details.
i used [Daily Total Female Births](https://drive.google.com/file/d/185VMdJ2AhOr4qqLvAXM38HrhhKkG_yM7/view?usp=sharing) Data for this purpose. it's a stationary time series.

```py
# importing packages
import pandas as pd
from pmdarima import auto_arima
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

# read csv file
df = pd.read_csv('/Data/DailyTotalFemaleBirths.csv' , index_col=0 , parse_dates=True)

# set daily frequency for datetime indexes
df.index.freq = 'D'

# now using auto_arima i try to find (p,d,q) orders for ARIMA model.
# so i set seasonal=False because i don't want orders for SARIMA! my
# goal is to find orders for ARIMA model not SARIMA
auto_arima(df['Births'] , start_P= 0 , start_q=0 , max_p=6 , 
            max_q=3 , d=None , error_action='ignore' , suppress_warnings=True ,
            m=12 , seasonal=False , stepwise=True).summary()
```

then it gives me this:
[image]

the problem is where although I set `seasonal=False` but it gives me SARIMAX (which stands for **Seasonal Autoregressive Independent Moving Average**) but I don't want to consider seasonal component, so I set `seasonal=False`! seems that `pmdarima` doesn't pay attention to `seasonal=False`!

can someone help me to figure out what is the problem?

---

Expected result:
[image]

for **False Result**: SARIMAX result comes from `pmdarima` version `1.8.3`
for **True Result**: ARIMA result comes from `pmdarima` version `1.1.0`

Comment: Looks like this changed in version [v1.5.1](https://github.com/alkaline-ml/pmdarima/blob/7c7618a79628d3deab8427e7c4aa5ebb89b505d9/doc/whats_new.rst#v151). pmdarima always uses SARIMAX now.

Comment: @NickODell are you sure? so you mean it's not a problem? **additional details:** in `pmdarima` version `1.8.3`, and exactly in this example; when I run `auto_arima(...).seasonal_order` it gives me `(0,0,0,0)` which can be interpreted as ignoring seasonal component I guess. what do you think about this?

Comment: I agree - that's the default value for the seasonal_order component, and per the documentation, the default seasonal order has no effect: `Default is no seasonal effect.` https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/e80fcedb71205ca26c345bd34389bacee36b0e53/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/sarimax.py#L50

Comment: @NickODell Thanks! I saw your mentioned references. so there's no problem there. Thank you for your help! it would be great if you Answer This Question then I'll verify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really using a seasonal model. It's just a confusing message.

In the pmdarima library, in version [v1.5.1](https://github.com/alkaline-ml/pmdarima/blob/master/doc/whats_new.rst#v151) they changed the statistical model in use from ARIMA to a more flexible and less buggy model called SARIMAX. (It stands for Seasonal Autoregressive Integrated Moving Average Exogenous.)

Despite the name, you can use it in a non-seasonal way by setting the seasonal terms to zero.

You can double-check whether the model is seasonal or not by using the following code:

```py
model = auto_arima(...)
print(model.seasonal_order)
```

If it shows as `(0, 0, 0, 0)`, then no seasonality adjustment will be done.